# Assign "this" to a variable

Tags: java

Is there any way this can be done in Java?

In PHP you can do `$someVar = $this;` and in JavaScript `var something = this;`

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Assuming your class name is `MyClass`

```
MyClass thisObject = this;
```

Alternatively, if you are in an inner, anonymous class, or something of the like, the following would be equivalent (given that you are in an instance of `MyClass` still)

```
MyClass thisObject = MyClass.this;
```

Comment: Or `return this;`, or pass `this` as an argument to a method (where it'll be bound to a variable within the method), or any number of other things.  You can use the value of `this` in pretty much the same ways you'd use a value stored in any other variable.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** "this" is associated with the **non-static members** in java.

**2.** this represents the **current object**.

**3.** `MyCustomClass mc = this ;`  **Will assign the current object to mc which is an object reference variable of type MyCustomClass.**

**4.** Suppose you are in inner class, you can do the following...

**eg:**

```
public class outer{

    int x = 10;

    class inner{

        int x=5;

        public void go(){
            System.out.println("Inner x: "+ this.x);           // Prints x in Inner class
            System.out.println("Inner x: "+ Outer.this.x);     // Prints x in Outer class
        }
    }
}
```